# The contents of C:\Windows folder is in C:\Windows\NEW folder

Tags: windows-xp, vmware

There is an old working laptop running on WinXP with a very specific installed software, the installations and keys to which, of course, have fallen into oblivion.
It was necessary to make a VMWare virtual machine of the system with VMware Converter. At the very end of the virtual machine creation, the converter bailed on the fact that it could not process the contents of the WINDOWS folder with its regxps. I went to see what happened, and there the contents of the *C:\Windows* folder is at *C:\Windows\NEW*. Have no idea why.
Question: how to transfer all the content from the *NEW* folder back to the *WINDOWS* folder?

Comment: You can't just drag & drop the contents of C:\Windows\New into C:\Windows?

Comment: I can but I'm sure it will ruin the WinXP

Comment: In a perfect world this would be possible. In a world full of buggy and poorly thought out software, as you have already experienced, it is not. There are likely far too many things hardcoded in different places to fix this. Programmers often fail to think about this ever happening. I’d suggest forgetting VMware and use a different tool. Perhaps Disk2VHD and Hyper-V? And forget about trying to move the folder.

Comment: Back in the XP days, Windows\New would have been created during an upgrade from a previous version of Windows.  So \Windows would hold the original version in case a rollback was needed.  You may be able to change your Environment Variables to point to \Windows.